# Why can't different stl implementations exist using NDK?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, ndk-build, ceres-solver

I try to build a project based on two open source libraries. The libraries I am using are OpenCV and ceres. The libopencv_java3.so is the release OpenCV3.1.2 from the website github that include OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk. The libceres.so is compiled from souce code by myself.

When I build my application, NDK-build generates following information:

> clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdlib++' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
>
> error: undefined reference to 'cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__ndk1::vector > const&)'

After googling, I find one related post

[Error Undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::locale::~locale()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183886/error-undefined-reference-to-std-ndk1localelocale)
The answer says that different STL implementations are used.

For my case, libopencv_java.so may use gnustl_static and libceres uses c++_static. 
I don't understand the reason. The two implementations are both static libraries and conflict should not occur.

1. Is all so files from opencv release compiled with gnustl_static?
2. Why __ndk1 appears in std::vector?
3. For one large project, different engineers take different sub-tasks. Should they link one common stl implementation? Is the requirement different for static linkage and dynamic linkage?

Comment: Say you want to pass a `std::vector` to both libraries which stl implementation should you use in the main project ?

Comment: The two libraries are both linked with STL implementation as static libraries. Is this still a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This answer come late, but I hope it might help someone coming across similar problems (as I do).

> Is all so files from opencv release compiled with gnustl_static?

It seems that OpenCV 3.X-android (even the latest 3.4.12 at the time of writing), uses `gnustl_statc`. That means all the stl components resides in namespace `std`.
However for OpenCV 4.X-android, the library has been compiled with `c++_static`, so the stl components are in the namespace `std::__ndk1`.

> Why __ndk1 appears in std::vector?

It is [*inline namespace*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016220/what-are-inline-namespaces-for/11018418#11018418).

> For one large project, different engineers take different sub-tasks. Should they link one common stl implementation? Is the requirement different for static linkage and dynamic linkage?

Not sure about that...